# How to add a blank space character to regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using asp.net (c#) and for validation of an email address field, I have the following regular expression:

```
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$"]
```

This works just fine except that when any leading/trailing white spaces are added to the email field, it throws an error as invalid email. How can I modify the regular expression in a way that it would accept such white spaces (later on in my code, I'll remove any spaces from either side so I store valid emails)? Thanks

Comment: By the way, `+` is a valid character in e-mail addresses. Gmail allows you to have `me@gmail.com` and then you can alias it like so: `me+alias@gmail.com`. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't sound right to allow spaces and you will trim off later, the regex is helping that scenario and providing that validation (although you should still check server side)

I think adding `(\\s*)` at the beginning and end should help you though.  i.e.

```
[RegularExpression("^(\\s*)[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\\s*)$")]
```

This is saying start or ends with whitespace

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Btw, the reason I am allowing for space and them trimming it, is that sometimes people copy their email address from another page/application and when pasted, somehow it comes with a space. They don't notice the space and I don't want to give them an error every time. Would be too inconvenient for the users.

Comment: For people reading this in the future: As I said on the original question, the `+` symbol is valid before the `@`, and typically allows the user to create an alias of their inbox. `\+` should be added to the first character set. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

This site also help https://regexr.com/